# Paste a range into a filtered table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, copy-paste

We have the following excel sheet:

[image: Start situation]

The cells A2 to A10 are filtered: option 3 and option 4 are filtered out. Now we want to paste the numbers in A12:A16 next to the visible cells (so in B2:B10). Any way how we could accomplish this?

Comment: @DaveRook: should be clearer

Comment: In B2 just add the code =SUM(A12) and like wise for the others - or is this going to be a dynamic query, meaning the cell references you've used will actually change based upon the results of Column1?

Comment: No, we have thousands of numbers from another sheet that we want to past in an existing table that's filtered. It's gonna be a one time paste, but doing this manually will take a long time.

Comment: And what is A12:A16? Is this an example of the figures from the other spreadsheet? Does their value change based upon the filter in Column1?

Comment: Yes, I've created a simplified copy to test it and to use it on here. Those 5 values represent the data we have to copy from the other sheet (so in fact thousand of numbers compared to the 5 here).

Comment: I think you'll have to do use a macro but as I don't understand your criteria, I suggest you look  http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-programming-range-excel-vba.html

Comment: There are alternatives to creating a macro

Answer (score 5):

Let Y and Z represent two scratch columns (i.e., beyond your data).

1. Move your data from A12-A16 to B12-B16.
2. In Y2, enter `=ROW()`. 
   (In Excel 2010, `=ROW` might work and might even be required.)
3. Drag down to Y10.
4. With Y2-Y10 selected, type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>**;**</kbd>. 
   (@Sean: Thanks for teaching me that trick!)
5. Copy; then click in A12 and paste.
6. Type `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Y2,A$12:B$16,2,FALSE),"")` into Z2
   and drag down to Z10. 
   (This should now look like the data in B12-B16.)
7. Turn off filtering.
8. Copy Z2-Z10, and paste values into B2-B10.
9. (Delete columns Y and Z.)

Comment: +1 for not using VBA.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find a way to paste and avoid hidden rows (I can copy just the visible items using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> before copying) without resorting to VBA.

This macro will copy A12:16 to B2, and down, skipping hidden rows

```
Sub Paste2VisRows()

Dim rFrom As Range, rTo As Range
Dim i As Long, Ofset As Long

Set rFrom = Range("A12:A16")
Set rTo = Range("B2")

For i = 1 To rFrom.Rows.Count
    Do Until Not rTo.Offset(Ofset).Rows.Hidden
        Ofset = Ofset + 1
    Loop
    rFrom.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=rTo.Offset(Ofset)
    Ofset = Ofset + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That (Alt)+; trick is neat, @Sean!  Where is it documented?

Comment: @Scott, there is a big list here: http://excelshortcuts.co.uk/excel-keyboard-shortcuts/

Comment: For idiots like me: Alt+Shift+, (don't forget to press shift :p )

Answer (score 1):

Copy the macro code from @SeanCheshire with little modifications so it will prompt user to select the copy area and paste area.

Copy area can select range, example A1:A10, 
Paste area just need to select 1 cell, example B11, if let said B12 to B14 is hidden, then it will paste to B11, B15, B16, ... B23

```
Sub Paste2VisRows()

Dim rFrom As Range, rTo As Range
Dim i As Long, Ofset As Long

Dim RngCopySelection As Range
Set RngCopySelection = Application.InputBox("Please select copy area", "Area Selection", , , , , , 8)

Dim RngPasteSelection As Range
Set RngPasteSelection = Application.InputBox("Please select paste area", "Area Selection", , , , , , 8)

Set rFrom = RngCopySelection
Set rTo = RngPasteSelection

For i = 1 To rFrom.Rows.Count
    Do Until Not rTo.Offset(Ofset).Rows.Hidden
        Ofset = Ofset + 1
    Loop
    rFrom.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=rTo.Offset(Ofset)
    Ofset = Ofset + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Hi, I had trouble with the above, (Excel 2007); it kept copying the last value in the "rangeFrom" into the cells below the "rangeTo". Unpredictably. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't. As a result I have a spreadsheet with approximately 100,000 rows of data which I now believe to be corrupted... D'OH!

So based on the above I have developed these Ideas with a couple of safety features:

```
Sub copyIntoFilteredRange()

Dim rTo As Range
Dim rFrom As Range
Dim j As Integer 
Dim k As Integer

Set rFrom = Application.InputBox("Select Copy Range", , , , , , , 8)
Set rTo = Application.InputBox("Select Paste Range", , , , , , , 8)

' The following If-Then segment ensures that ranges are the same size:
If rFrom.Rows.Count = rTo.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count Then


j = 1
' j will count until the correct number of cells is copied

Do While j < rFrom.Rows.Count

    For k = 1 To rTo.Rows.Count
    ' k will iterate through the whole of the rTo Range including hidden cells, and 
    ' copying will only happen as long as 1. j <= no. of cells in range and
    ' 2. The cell is not hidden.
        If rTo.Rows(k).Hidden = False Then
            rFrom.Rows(j).Copy Destination:=rTo.Rows(k)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next k

Loop


Else

    MsgBox "The sizes do not match"

End If


End Sub
```

I am new to VBA (more comfortable with Java, and novice at that too), so please point out the errors of my ways if necessary.

Cheers for the help!

Ben

Comment: Should have said, Thanks to cww and Sean Cheshire for providing original code.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to sort the required rows to the top of the table, paste the data and then resort back into original order.

1. Fill a separate temporary column with ones
2. Remove filter
3. Make sure only cells on rows with required data is filled with ones
4. Numerate the whole table in another column
5. Sort table in ascending order using ones
6. Paste the required data
7. Restore the original order by using numerated column
8. Delete temporary columns

Notes.
* Using Office 2007. 
* In my understanding this the only logical way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Office 2013 and above there is a much elegant solution: 
It is the Flash Fill (ctrl+E)  - (Ribbon Home- Editing - Fill -Flash Fill ) 
But Flash Fill is tricky, -not as simple as Ctrl+V- because you should give at least one example in the destination for make it work!

So how it works.

1. step 1:  Copy first cell of source and
2. paste the value to the cell on filtered destination. This is the "example".
3. Select all the source cells, and ctrl+C
4. put the cursor on cell recently updated on destination, then
5. "ctrl+e" will flashfill.
   (Only the visible /filtered cells will be filled from source.)

We love Flash Fill for data pasted to filtered destination.

Answer (score 0):

HerLoW

An alternative solution without looping but requiring helper columns and formulas.

As example , I use the original question example  range and requirement:    Filtred.JPG : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc0DE.jpg

This will fill all the rows, as required in column B , and also fill the hidden rows with the hidden value from column A

```
Sub StkItFiltrPste()
Range("A12:A16").Insert shift:=xlToRight
Range("A2:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Range("A12")
Range("B2:B10").Value = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,A$12:B$16,2,FALSE)),A2,VLOOKUP(A2,A$12:B$16,2,FALSE))"
Range("B2:B10").Value = Range("B2:B10").Value
End Sub
```

.

This next alternative, will fill all the rows, as required in column B , and leave the hidden rows empty

```
Sub StkItFiltrPste2()
Range("A12:A16").Insert shift:=xlToRight
Range("A2:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Range("A12")
Range("B2:B10").Value = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,A$12:B$16,2,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(A2,A$12:B$16,2,FALSE))"
Range("B2:B10").Value = Range("B2:B10").Value
End Sub
```

Results:
CopyToFiltred.JPG : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTFZS.jpg

Tabelle2 here: 'AfterFiltering.xlsm' :  https://app.box.com/s/1ppn71a3tbit3fi62pz73dklkeniqzjw

Ref: http://www.eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=34116&p=264509#p264509

Alan